# Prove $\sin x<x$ when $x>0$ and $x\leq 2\pi$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I understand that the mean value theorem says that at some point in the interval there will be a tangent with the same slope as the average slope of the interval.

As far as I know, this means it can be less or more, undetermined. I also know that $-1\leq \sin(x)\leq 1$ in the interval $(0,2\pi)$.

What I don't understand is how this is used to prove $sin(x)<x$  if $0<x\leq 2\pi$

[image]

To sum up we know:

- The function input interval is $(0, 2\pi$)
- The function  values in this interval are in $[-1,1]$
- We want to show that the input value is greater than the function output value for every input value
- Based on the image we know that the average slope is less than $1$ as $\cos c<1$

What is the reasoning that allows one to conclude that?

Comment: We have $\sin x/x<1$ and $x>0$, so multiply both sides by $x$.

Comment: OP is trying to understand why $\sin x/x < 1$.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to apply the mean-value theorem to the interval $(0,x)$. The average slope of the interval is $\frac{\sin x-\sin 0}{x-0}$. By the mean-value theorem, there exists $c\in(0,x)\subseteq(0,2\pi)$ such that
$$\frac{\sin x-\sin 0}{x-0}=\sin'c=\cos c.$$
Since $\cos <1$ on $(0,2\pi)$, we find
$$\frac{\sin x}{x}<1.$$
Multiplying both sides by $x>0$, we conclude that $\sin x<x$.

Answer (score 0):

Quite elementary: as by hypothesis, $x>0$,  from $\frac{\sin x}x<1$, we deduce instantly that
$$\frac{\sin x}{\not x}\cdot \not x< 1\cdot x=x.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't understand it at all, however.

Comment: Do you agree with $\frac{\sin x}x<1$?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I do understand that sin x/x<1 and how you get that sin x<x from that. But not where sin x/x<1 comes from.

Comment: From the fact that $\frac{\sin x}x=\cos c$ for some $c\in (0,x)$. A cosine can't be more than $1$.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that the mean-value theorem was used to prove that $\frac{\sin x}{x} < 1$, by proving that you can always find a $c \in [0, 2\pi]$ for which $\frac{\sin x}{x} = \cos c$. Why was the theorem chosen for the proof you have? That's basically experience and trial and error, like, if you know what you have to prove, you can try and test out some theories; and by chance, basically, it turns out that you can actually show what's in the proof you showed. At least, this is coming from what I understood of your question ('What is the reasoning that allows one to conclude that?')